# Java Slick2d lighting using Raycasting

Tags: java, lighting, graphics-programming, slick

I am trying to make a top down view game in java using the Slick2d library, for lighting I wanted to do something like this : http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/.
I was wondering if there was a way to tint or light places on the screen in Slick. I would have my map rendering in the background and a lightmap in front.

Solution :
https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d/blob/master/src/org/newdawn/slick/tests/AlphaMapTest.java

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to check this project, [Shade](https://github.com/aschearer/shade). 
There is real-time lighting and moving shadows, I think could be useful for you

[image]

Comment: You don't answer his/her question with this.

Comment: I've tried to suggest a complete game with the required mechanics

Comment: @Vokall he askedfor a way to tint stuff in slick. What if that game gets removed? Your answer then becomes useless.